# Declaring a variable once and using it in a function

Tags: c#

I want to create a method of a class. (Edited: Using Dmitry's Example):

```
public class MyClass 
{
  // variable 'a' is initialize as a = 5 only once
  private string c = string.empty;
  private static int a;

  private void CalculateSum(int b)
  {

    if(c==null)
    {
        c="abc";
        a=5;
    }


   // every time the function is called it uses this (a) value
    int sum  = a + b;

    // But if sum = 10... 
    if (sum == 10)
    {
        // then value of 'a' changes to 10
        a = 10; 
    }
  }

  // Some other code here 
}
```

Now, when the function is called the first time, 'a' if set a value of 5. Now, when the function is called the second time, will it still store the value 5 ?

Comment: You're setting `a` to equal `sum` in the `if` statement. If you don't want the value to change, don't assign anything to it.

Comment: Every time function is called is `a` starting as 5 or is it updated with each call?

Comment: Also, if you want the sum to be returned, you should change it to be a function, `private int CalculateSum(int b)` and return the results, `return sum;`

Comment: Always post a short but complete program for these sort of questions.  Your program is short, but incomplete.  We don't see the full context of the `a` variable.

Comment: What is your question? It's really not clear. Do you ask how to declare the 'a' variable once? Please provide more info.

Comment: I want the value of 'a' to change only when it hits a particular condition. Else it should always consider the starting value (a=5). Every time the function is called, 'a' uses the value of 5 if the value wasn't updated to 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague one. It seems that you want to implement something like this

```
public class MyClass 
{
  // variable 'a' is initialize as a = 5 only once
  private int a = 5;

  private void CalculateSum(int b)
  {
    // every time the function is called it uses this (a) value
    int sum  = a + b;

    // But if sum = 10... 
    if (sum == 10)
    {
        // then value of 'a' changes to 10
        a = 10; 
    }
  }

  // Some other code here 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to verify if this will work, if I declare 'a' as a member variable of the class and initialize it once.

Comment: I have another question.

Comment: If 'a' is not initialized when declaring it and in the function if we do, if(a==null) { a=5;}. In this case, next time the function is called will it retain the value of 'a' ? Or doing the same thing after declaring 'private static int a' will it retain the value of 'a' that we set previously ?

Comment: @AbhilashHazarika, a is an `int` and therefore cannot be `null`.  But to answer your question generally, variables will retain their values as long as 1.  You don't change them yourself, and 2.  They stay in scope.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, the second time the function will be called, the value of 'a' will be 5 (If not changed to 10 per your condition).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cleared my confusion.